# How to implement an onmousedown and onmouseup on an iPhone touch screen

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari, onmousedown, onmouseup

I've very new to HTML/JavaScript but am learning…

I want to make a button on an iPhone that runs a JavaScript command when it is pressed and another when it is released.  I tried to do this using `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` properties, but this does not work the same on iPhone.

```html
<input type="image" onmousedown="command_press()" onmouseup="command_release()" src="images/UP-Dark.png" alt="" title="" />
```

Could someone please tell me how to do the same thing on the iPhone?

Answer (score 48):

The equivalent for `onmousedown` on touchscreen devices is `ontouchstart`, and the equivalent of `onmouseup` is `ontouchend`.

If you would also like to detect dragging, you could use `ontouchmove` which is fired every time you move your finger after touching the screen.

Comment: Note this will fire twice if you use like `element.onmousedown = element.onkeydown = element.ontouchstart = function() { /* event handler... */ }`. Replacing the mouse and touch event with the `onpointerdown` instead, as [recommended in Zectbumo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50488754/1201863), fixes this problem.

Answer (score 40):

You might be interested in `onpointerup` and `onpointerdown` events which will work on both touch and non touch devices. [Check browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer)

Comment: Zectbumo, you are a life saver.  Thanks