# HTML onmousedown event not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I have made a prank calculator which takes an input from the user of the answer to be displayed when the '=' button is pressed. The input is taken in the form of a prompt in JavaScript which is triggered by long-pressing the '0' button. The long press feature is implemented by setting a timeout of 2 seconds when the buttons is pressed (using `onmousedown`) and clearing the timeout when the mouse key is lifted (`onmouseup`). This works fine on computers, but I don't know how to implement this on mobile. I have tried the `onpointerdown` and `onpointerup` events too. These also work fine on computers, but when I long-press on mobile, the prompt displays a second time shortly afterwards. The HTML and JavaScript code relating to this is as follows:

HTML:

```
          <td>
            <button
              class="calculator-button"
              onclick="insert(0)"
              onmousedown="activateMagic()"
              onmouseup="disableMagic()"
            >
              0
            </button>
          </td>
```

JavaScript:

```
let answer = null;
const input = document.getElementById("calcInput");
let pressTimer;

const insert = (objToInsert) => {
  input.value += objToInsert;
};

const clearInput = () => {
  input.value = null;
  answer = null;
};

const activateMagic = () => {
  pressTimer = window.setTimeout(() => {
    answer = prompt("Enter the prank answer: ");
  }, 2000);
  return false;
};

const disableMagic = () => {
  clearTimeout(pressTimer);
};

const findAnswer = () => {
  if (answer == null) {
    let problemAnswer = eval(input.value);
    setTimeout(() => {
      input.value = problemAnswer;
    }, 10);
  }

  input.value = answer;
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement a onmousedown and onmouseup on a touch screen iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009821/how-to-implement-a-onmousedown-and-onmouseup-on-a-touch-screen-iphone)

Comment: I'm glad, that I've helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer!! @DanyloHalaiko was right. The `touchstart` and `touchend` event listeners *actually* work! To those of you interested or those of you seeing this in the future, this is my final code:

HTML:

```
          <td>
            <button
              class="calculator-button"
              onclick="insert(0)"
              onmousedown="activateMagic()"
              onmouseup="disableMagic()"
              id="activateBtn"
            >
              0
            </button>
          </td>
```

JavaScript:

```
let answer = null;
const input = document.getElementById("calcInput");
const activateBtn = document.getElementById("activateBtn");
let pressTimer;

const insert = (objToInsert) => {
  input.value += objToInsert;
};

const clearInput = () => {
  input.value = null;
  answer = null;
};

const activateMagic = () => {
  pressTimer = window.setTimeout(() => {
    answer = prompt("Enter the prank answer: ");
  }, 2000);
  return false;
};

const disableMagic = () => {
  clearTimeout(pressTimer);
};

activateBtn.addEventListener("touchstart", activateMagic);
activateBtn.addEventListener("touchend", disableMagic);

const findAnswer = () => {
  if (answer == null) {
    let problemAnswer = eval(input.value);
    setTimeout(() => {
      input.value = problemAnswer;
    }, 10);
  }

  input.value = answer;
};
```